# Relative link working in IE but not Chrome

Tags: html, url

So I have a website at foo.com/vpn/faq.xml which has several links to sub faq pages like foo.com/vpn/faq/pageOne.xml and foo.com/vpn/faq/pageTwo.xml.  The .xml files under the faq folder refer to an FAQ.xsl file.

This FAQ.xsl file has the following code:

```
<div><a href="..\faq.xml"><img alt="" border="0" src="..\images\r_2.gif" align="middle"/><b>FAQ</b></a></div>
```

This works correctly in internet explorer - it takes the user up one level in the hierarchy back to faq.xml.  In chrome, however, it provides as the link "foo.com\vpn\faq..%5Cfaq.xml" rather than jumping up a level in the hierarchy to  foo.com\vpn\faq.xml

Is there some change I can make that will make the link work correctly in both ie and chrome? (and hopefully other browsers as well.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Uri's use forward slashes.  Browsers escape certain characters differently, but it's a moot point here because the backslashes are incorrect.

From [the spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt):

> The generic syntax uses the slash ("/"), question mark ("?"), and
>   number sign ("#") characters to delimit components that are
>   significant to the generic parser's hierarchical interpretation of an 
>   identifier.

Comment: OK, so your suggestion then is that I change the code to: 
    <div><a href="../faq.xml"><img alt="" border="0" src="../images/r_2.gif" align="middle"/><b>FAQ</b></a></div> 
?

Comment: @NewPowerSheller, yes, that should do it.